# Find topology jar version running in Apache Storm

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I have a running storm topology started using a packaged jar.  I'm trying to find the version of the jar the topology is running.  As far as I can tell, Storm will only show the version of Storm that is running, not the version of the topology running.

Running the "storm version" command only gives the version of storm running and I don't see anything in the topology section of the Storm UI to indicate topology version.

Is there any way to have Storm report this or is my best bet setting a properties file?  Ideally, this would be done automatically with either the pom.xml version or a git commit hash.  Another solution I'd be happy with would be to have Storm report on the jar file name used to start the topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to list the

> $STORM_HOME/storm-local/supervisor/stormdist/name-of-your-running-topology

while the topology is running, and look at the stormjar.jar file. This is the uber jar used by storm when submitting the topology. Comparing the size of this jar with the uber jar generated from your java project build command, they should be identical and give you hint about the jar version used.

Comment: I think this is as close as we could get with "versioning" the jar.